# Intellij Idea debug with thread

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm new with Intellij Idea and I find it a good IDE. I'm using it for a distributed system project and (as you can imagine) I heavily use thread and concurrent programming and tools like timeout etc.

My problem is that it seems that the debugger doesn't stop time-flow while the debugger is stopped on a breakpoint line.

I'll try to explain myself better. I have a `future` that I use as timeout for a thread task: if it doesn't complete the task in a certain time then arise a `TimeoutException` and do some stuff, otherwise do other. The problem is that with the debugger this timeout seems to don't stop during breakpoint lines, so the behavior of the program is different depending on the debugger or normal execution.

Is it that normal? There is any way to solve it?

Comment: There's no problem with IntelliJ; it's the best Java IDE on the market.  It's your lack of understanding of threads that is the issue.  Time does not stop because of a debugger.

Comment: Well I thought that was possible in someway, I find that this is a big problem debugging! It's the first time that I try to debug with threads. How am I supposed to debug my multi-thread program without using breakpoints (except using ad-hoc print obviously)?

Comment: Maybe you need to hone your skills so you're not so dependent on the debugger? It's an excellent tool, but you can't expect it to stop time.

Comment: It's not possible; not a big problem.  You can debug your multi-thread programs; you can't stop time.  That's all.  Try mocking that timed task for your test so it behaves deterministically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: Run -> View breakpoints -> find your breakpoint -> First checkbox (`Suspend`). Try Setting suspend mode to `Thread` instead of `All`. So only thread where breakpoint occurs will be suspended instead of all threads in your application. Or try to disable `Suspend` for this breakpoint. Instead of suspending you can log some message to console. Look at `Log message to console` or `Log evaluated expression` options. This is for Idea 12. Idea 14 as I know has same options.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal, and this works that way with any other debugger. `TimeoutException` happens based on the actual time passed in the system, and no debugger is unfortunately able to stop the flow of time.